# Searchbar in ios 8?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I've seen much of the apple documentation, many examples, and some github projects.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

and

http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

are ios 7 only.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html
is confusing with a lot of unnecessary clutter complicating it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift is for swift only, but seems to be exactly what I need if it someone could translate it to objective c.

I don't get it at all.

If someone could just tell me step by step the differences, or maybe a simple breakdown, that would help.

It seemed to be a lot easier in ios 7, why did they change it?

Even when I drag a search bar controller in the storyboard editor, and link it to my header, the default property and name is uisearchdisplaycontroller which is deprecated.

I also have another question that can't easily be googled:

If I have a table view, it's easy to know what was selected.

But when I select or edit the search results, 
how do I know what to do to the table view array, if the index paths will be different?

Comment: I just did a manual hook up of my table and searchbar.text

Comment: [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) has many examples of using UISearchController in Obj-C